# References for generalization bounds?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bounds, pac-learning

I'm looking for references (books, papers, lecture notes etc) on generalization bounds and their proofs. Specifically, I'm looking to fully understand the technique of defining a hypothesis class (or distribution) and using a concentration inequality to obtain a generalization bound.

What are the standard references for such techniques?

Comment: So far I've found these lecture notes( https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse546/15au/lectures/lecture18_erm.pdf ), but I'm looking for more examples of generalization bounds.

Comment: Although this is a rather introductory review, here (http://bit.ly/2JeaDfs) you'll find a long list of references with focus on Deep Learning. Maybe helps.